# How to get the python libraries/packages required to a production environment which doesn't have pip?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have created a Python application and now I need to deploy it to UAT and production environments which don't have access to pip library (the environment doesn't have access to internet).

I was told to put all the libraries in a folder `python-lib`. Should I just copy the all the content in `anaconda3\lib\site-packages\` to the folder? However, it has several hundred mega bytes. Is it a way to copy the libraries just needed by my application?

Comment: I was told I need to include all the library I use in the folder `python-lib`. `pip` is not available.

Comment: Do you have anaconda/miniconda also on the target machines?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create a virtual environment locally and install the packages needed to it like so:

```sh
$ python3 -m venv prod_env
$ source prod_env/bin/activate
$ pip install <package_name>
```

If the folder is too large you can always compress and unzip on the UAT/Prod box.

Once the packages are installed in the virtual environment that are dependencies for your app, move the `prod_env` folder to the prod/UAT environment using `scp` or whatever method you normally would.

After the folder is moved to the environment you'll need to go into the `bin` folder and edit the `activate` script. You'll need to edit the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable to be the path that the virtual environment is located on your prod/UAT box.

Once that's done you should be able to activate the virtual environment as normal:

```sh
$ source /path/to/prod_env/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pip -t`

```
mkdir libs
python -m pip -r requirements.txt -t libs
```

Then add the path to `PYTHONPATH`. Now sure if there is any default PYTHONPATH for a module/script.